# saving mapped collection in new entity

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I've read the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-persistent) and thought I'd be able to do the following....

map my classes as so (which does work)

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity
{
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<ChildEntity> children;
...
}

@Entity
public class ChildEntity
{
...
    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id;
...
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private ParentEntity parent;
...
}
```

.. but i want to be able to insert into both tables in one go and thought this would work:

```
parent = new ParentEntity();
parent.setChildren(new ArrayList<ChildEntity>());
ChildEntity child = new ChildEntity();
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
session.persist(parent);
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing?

Do i need to save the parent first, then add the child and save it again?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)`. You can also have `CascadeType.ALL` which includes persist, merge, delete...

Cascading is the setting that tells hibernate what to do with collection elements when the owning entity is persisted/merged/deleted.

By default it does nothing with them. If the respective cascade type is set, it invokes the same operation for the collection elements that were invoked for the parent.